# Conditional custom post type while post ID is - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to add content to specific custom post type page?

I am using this code

```
is_singular()
```

I wanted to add content to  custom post type, but for specific page only.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out using get_the_id.

The code is something like this

```
is_singular('custom-post-slug') && get_the_id() == 123 ): ?>
```

"custom-post-slug" is the slug of the custom post type
"123" is the page ID

Answer (score 0):

In these cases you can i always add single-{custom-post-type}.php in the theme and define specials html structure for that like following code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="single-page-customtype">
    Hello Single
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2415803 it a bad practice to hardcode ID like this please consider using custom fields or some other checks to get the desired ID.

Can you please provide more information? If you are trying to add content for specific custom post type just use this :

```
if ( get_post_type() === 'your_post_type_name' ) {
 // add the content
}
```

Please note that you can extend the if condition to be for specific page and so on. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hello, I got it working using this code is_singular('custom-post-slug') && get_the_id() == 123 ): ?> , I need to add some content in WordPress specific page which this specific page is under custom post type. Thank you